# Is it possible to merge two different AVAudioPlayer tracks

Tags: swift, swift4, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiofile

I have two instances of AVAudioPlayer playing two different tracks with different volume and rate (One is instrumental track and other is recording of song). I want to merge those two tracks to a single one. Is it possible to do it with AVAudioPlayer or should I go for some other approach?